# Moving the background image in mit app inventor

Tags: app-inventor

Is it possible to move the background image in app inventor?

I'm trying to use the call canvas background pixel color block to get the color of different parts of the background. If I can't move the background image, can I use math blocks to change the x and y parts of the call canvas background pixel color block to a variable?

Comment: see these canvas examples for ideas https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/app-inventor-developers-library/canvas%7Csort:date

Answer (score 0):

*Important Note*
I am referring to the image sprite, under the drawings and animations tab.

An image will have coordinates once you put it inside of a canvas. In order to move it, create 2 sliders with 2 balls and 2 narrow canvases that are (seemingly) equal to the ball's diameter. (Place underneath the image, make sure the image isn't too big)

Go into blocks and place the "when dragged" command, and hook up the change in the ball's x/y to the change of the images x/y. (Assuming you know how to make the ball move while you drag it, also very simplistic). This will make the image's movement equal to the ball's movement (1:1 ratio) Depending on how much you want the image to move, your'e going to have to implement a ratio.

When you drag the ball(s), the image should move with it.